# How to run "jmx_prometheus_javaagent" on a secured kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

I am trying to add prometheus jmx agent (jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar) to an existing secured kafka cluster(SSL/SASL enabled on brokers).

But when I run the java agent, I am not getting response on the port as it says-

```
curl http://serv010134:8080
curl: (7) Failed connect to serv010134:8080; Connection refused
```

My configs are:

```
$ cat confluent-kafka.service

[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka - broker
Documentation=http://docs.confluent.io/
After=network.target confluent-zookeeper.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=cp-kafka
Group=confluent
Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/opt/monitoring/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=8080:/opt/monitoring/prometheus/kafka-2_0_0.yml"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties
TimeoutStopSec=180
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Kafka yml:

```
$ cat kafka-2_0_0.yml
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern : .*
```

The same above settings work fine in an unsecured kafka cluster.
Am I missing anything? 
Ideally the above steps should throw the metrics on the 8080 port and I can curl it.
note- firewalls on the machine are disabled.(flat network)

PS- I tried above steps for zookeeper also and and I am able to see the metrics for it. I am suspecting this has something to do with SSL configs of brokers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved after replacing the variable KAFKA_OPTS to EXTRA_ARGS.